# Url Redirection

Tags: asp.net, url

There are 2 website domain names; one is www.website.com.tr, and the other is website.com.tr .

All I want to do is, if the user writes to the browser's address bar website.com.tr,  I want the 3w version to be opened.

Is it possible to do this by writing some server-side code like:

```
if (givenURL=="website.com.tr")
{
   url.Redirect("www.website.com.tr");
}
```

... or am I better off to pasting below code block to the global.asax file?

```
private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication) sender;

    if (!application.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http://www."))
    {
        application.Response.Redirect(
            application.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://", "http://www."));
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to the create a CNAME record on the DNS server to map both URLs to the same application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to [handle this at the web server](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008) or even at DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your domain name to work with, why not just set up DNS to redirect website.com.tr to www.website.com.tr?  My hosting company did it by default for me.